# How to return distinct values in a JSON_ARRAYAGG

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I'm attempting to place the results of a distinct, single-column query into a JSON array so it can be used on my web server.  I have it set up something like this:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'ArrayKey' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( col ) 
) AS jsonResult
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT column_name AS col
       FROM tbl_name);
```

However, when this query returns results, the array it generates in JSON contains all values from my column and ignores the DISTINCT clause in the subquery somehow.  Whenever I get rid of the JSON_ARRAYAGG clause and output the results directly, the result are unique, but somehow the command is ignored when I add it back in.  I've also attempted to place the DISTINCT clause inside the JSON_ARRAYAGG as well, like so:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'ArrayKey' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( DISTINCT col ) 
) AS jsonResult
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT column_name AS col
       FROM tbl_name);
```

to no avail.  Does anyone know what's going wrong in my code that's causing the array to output all values instead of distinct ones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting... Looks like a bug to me. The optimizer seems to push down too eagerly.

As workaround you can use the `NO_MERGE` hint on the subquery.

```
SELECT /*+NO_MERGE(x)*/
      json_object('ArrayKey'
                  VALUE json_arrayagg(column_name)) jsonresult
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                   column_name
                   FROM tbl_name) x;
```

A CTE and a `MATERIALIZE` hint seem to work too.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT /*+MATERIALIZE*/ 
       DISTINCT
       column_name
       FROM tbl_name
)
SELECT json_object('ArrayKey'
                   VALUE json_arrayagg(column_name)) jsonresult
       FROM cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7e554da90b21365c14b48cec13ce380)

Answer (score 3):

This was a bug, we fixed it. You can try it out on live SQL

```
create table tbl_name (column_name number);
insert into tbl_name values(1);
insert into tbl_name values(1);
insert into tbl_name values(2);


SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
'ArrayKey' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( col ) 
) AS jsonResult
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT column_name AS col
     FROM tbl_name);

{"ArrayKey" : [1,2]}
```

The bug is
Bug 27757725 - JSON GENERATION AGGREGATION FUNCTIONS IGNORE DISTINCT
you can request a backport from Oracle Support Services

Answer (score 1):

I've found this hack to work:

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
  'ArrayKey' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG( col ) 
) AS jsonResult
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT column_name AS col
       FROM tbl_name)
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(*);
```

See also: [Oracle bug produces duplicate aggregate values in JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68191438/521799)